# Why is this code taking so long after function execution?

Tags: python, performance

```
import time

def some_function(x):
    t = time.time()
    #do something random
    y = x*x
    delta = 1000000*(time.time() - t)
    print("function took " + str(delta) + " microsecond")
    
    return y

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    x = 4
    t1 = time.time()
    ret_val = some_function(x)
    delta_t = 1000000*(time.time() - t1)
    print("everything took " + str(delta_t) + " microsecond")
```

In my main function I'm timing how long the function is going to take, and *inside* the function I'm timing how much it takes for all the lines of code to execute.

My assumption was that this time would be very very similar. However right after `some_function()` gets executed in the main file there is some lag because the output of the code is this:

```
function took 0.476837158203125 microsecond
everything took 30962.94403076172 microsecond
```

Comment: Printing to standard out takes a lot of time compared to x*x, the measurements are simply to small to infer anything.

Comment: Could be garbage collection, as anything referenced only by local variables in `some_function` will be recycled once the function exits.

Comment: Does this happen consistently? I was getting 0.0 microseconds for both, so I replaced `y = x*x` with a `for i in range(1_000_000): y += x` and now the maximum difference I've seen so far is ~1 millisecond

Comment: Benchmarking is not a trivial task, not at all. Take a look at IPython's `%timeit` if you want something a little more precise and pretty easy to use :)

Comment: @NiziL `%%timeit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [instrumentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_(computer_programming)) needs to avoid adding its own overhead to the process.  Printing takes a relatively large amount of time so you should only do it at the end once all measurements have been collected.  This may require your function to provide the time delta as a return value (or through global variables):

```
import time

def some_function(x):
    t = time.time()
    #do something random
    for _ in range(10000): y = x*x
    delta = time.time() - t    
    return y,delta

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    x = 4
    t1 = time.time()
    ret_val,f_delta = some_function(x)
    delta_t = time.time() - t1
    print("function took " + str(1000000*f_delta) + " microsecond")
    print("everything took " + str(1000000*delta_t) + " microsecond")

function took 661.8499755859375 microsecond
everything took 664.2341613769531 microsecond
```

There's actually only 2-5 miroseconds cost to the function call (including the internal time measurement overhead). This varies by a large percentage on each run because such small time intervals are subject to all sorts of interference from everything else running on your computer.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is huge help. I guess I didn't think the overhead cost would be so large and my example didn't have a loop which exaggerated the time difference